# SFTP through Paramiko: Errno 10061 (probably proxy)

Tags: python, proxy, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to connect to SFTP server using Paramiko in Python 2.7.

Here is my code:

```
# Python 2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import paramiko

# Connect to Server
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('ip_address',port = 22,username='user',password='password')
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have searched this issue in different places but still haven't found any decisions.

Port and other credentials to this server are correct. That's for sure, because I can connect to it through SFTP client FileZilla.
The code above is working from my personal machine, but it doesn't work from my corporate computer. That's why I think it's because of proxy.

Do you have any suggestions how can I go through proxy in this case?

I already have had environment variables

```
http_proxy='http://username:password@proxy:port'
https_proxy='https://username:password@proxy:port'
```

Any help would be valuable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paramiko itself does not implement proxies.

You have to provide a custom implementation of a "socket" via the `sock` parameter of the [`connect` method](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect).

The `httplib.HTTPConnection` can be used as such implementation for HTTP proxies.

For some examples, see:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20200208133623/https://www.adimian.com/blog/2014/10/paramiko-and-corporate-proxies/
- [How to ssh over HTTP proxy in Python Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10488832/850848)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! Now it is look like it's working.