# How do I re-create pysftp.Connection with a proxy parameter?

Tags: python, proxy, paramiko, pysftp

I am connecting to an SFTP server using `pysftp` but need to reconfigure it to go through a proxy. Since pysftp doesn't support it, I'm thinking of using `Paramiko`.

Looks like I'm utilizing the benefits of pysftp.Connection, since it looks like my code is using recursive file transfers.

What are the steps I would need to do to re-create `pysftp.Connection` but with the option to use a proxy? Looking through [the codebase](https://bitbucket.org/dundeemt/pysftp/src/master/pysftp/__init__.py) is a little frightening since I'm not sure what to edit...

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
import pysftp
import paramiko

hostname, prot = 'some.host.name', 22
proxy = paramiko.proxy.ProxyCommand('/usr/bin/nc --proxy proxy.foobar:8080 %s %d' % (hostname, port))
t = paramiko.Transport(sock=proxy)
t.connect(username='abc', password='123')

sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t) # back to pysftp wrapper
sftp.listdir('.')
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55670436/13448727) the origin of the code, with some discussion.