# How to connect to SFTP server through proxy in Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I'm trying to connect to SFTP server. I've found pysftp library which enables to connect to sftp but I've been trying to get my head around how to inject my proxy setting into the code. There's CnOpts object but it has no method when it comes to proxy.
Do you have any idea how to get it done?

Here's my code:

```py
import pysftp

# Define SFTP connection parameters
sftp_host = 'my_host'
sftp_port = 22  # SFTP port is usually 22
sftp_username = 'my_username'
sftp_password = 'password'
sftp_remote_path = 'path'
local_path = 'local_path'

# Define proxy settings
proxy_host = 'my_proxy'
proxy_port = my_port  # Replace with the actual proxy port
proxy_type = 'http'  # Choose the appropriate proxy type (socks4, socks5, http)

# Create a connection options object with proxy settings
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()

cnopts.proxy = pysftp.proxy(proxy_type=proxy_type, host=proxy_host, port=proxy_port) 

# Connect to the SFTP server through the proxy
with pysftp.Connection(host=sftp_host, port=sftp_port, username=sftp_username,
                       password=sftp_password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    # Download a file from the SFTP server
    sftp.get(sftp_remote_path, local_path)
    print(f"File downloaded successfully: {local_path}")
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36005078